# Mark as read option in notification in MacOS

Tags: macos, electron, cross-platform, electron-packager

I'm building a messaging app using electron. I am able to reply from the notification but did not find any sources to make the notification as read.

I am using the default `Notification API` provided by electron but it just has a parameter `hasReply` and not `hasRead`. I have also tried using `node-mac-notifier` which provides the same functionality.

Referencing only the useful part of code:

```
const notifications = new Map();

ipcMain.on(
    'notification',
    (_event: ElectronEvent, {id, title, body, icon, silent}: NotificationEvent) => {
        const notification = new Notification({
            title,
            body: config.get('notificationMessagePreview') ? body : `You have a new message`,
            hasReply: true,
            icon: nativeImage.createFromDataURL(icon),
            silent
        });

        notifications.set(id, notification);

        notification.on('click', () => {
            sendAction('notification-callback', {callbackName: 'onclick', id});

            notifications.delete(id);
        });

        notification.on('reply', (_event, reply: string) => {
            // We use onclick event used by messenger to go to the right convo
            sendBackgroundAction('notification-reply-callback', {callbackName: 'onclick', id, reply});

            notifications.delete(id);
        });

        notification.on('close', () => {
            sendBackgroundAction('notification-callback', {callbackName: 'onclose', id});
            notifications.delete(id);
        });

        notification.show();
    }
);
```

Expected to find a way to mark the message as read given the notification. Appreciated if using the default Notification API (though not mandatory)

Comment: Have you tried using [`notification.close()`](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/notification#notificationclose)?

Comment: But the notification doesn't show any `mark as read` button as of now. I'm not able to figure out how to give that option in notifications